# Changing background-color with javascript

Tags: javascript

I trying to change bg-color when I click on `button` element, and it works but it only change on first click. I want to be able to constantly change body `background` when I click on button.
DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/4Be9K/

Comment: Just put your red, green, blue variable generation in the click event handler so they will execute on every click not just once/

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
var d = document, 
btnElem = d.querySelector("button"), 
bodyElem = d.querySelector("body");

function randomBg () {
  var red = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
  var green = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
  var blue = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
  bodyElem.style.backgroundColor = 'rgb(' + red + ',' + green + ',' + blue + ')';    
}

btnElem.onclick = randomBg;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4Be9K/2/)):

```
var d = document, 
btnElem = d.querySelector("button"), 
bodyElem = d.querySelector("body");

btnElem.onclick = function() {
    bodyElem.style.backgroundColor = 'rgb(' + Math.floor(Math.random() * 256) + ',' + Math.floor(Math.random() * 256) + ',' + Math.floor(Math.random() * 256) + ')';
}
```

The reason it didn't work is because you were calling the `randomBg()` once which was generating the colours. After that it didn't generate any more colours.